# The Sum and Direct Sum of Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum

Calculate $S + T$ and determine if the sum is direct for the following subspaces of $\mathbf R^3$

a) $ S = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbf R^3 : x =z\}$
$ T = \{(x,y,z) \in R^3 : z = 0\}$

b) $ S = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbf R^3 : x = y\}$
$ T = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbf R^3 : x = y = z\}$

c) $ S = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbf R^3 : x = y = 0\}$
$ T = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbf R^3 : x = z\}$

OK, so in this first case, I will first include my own approach to the problem (using a method I reached with someone who was helping me) and then I will include a classmate's approach which seems simpler. My own approach:

Note that I use B to refer to the Basis of a subspace

$v \in S+T \iff \exists s \in S, t \in T | v = s + t$

$S : (x,y,z) = (x,y,x) = x \cdot (1,0,1) + y \cdot (0,1,0)$
$B_S = \{(1,0,1) , (0,1,0)\}$
$T : (x,y,z) = (x,y,0) = x \cdot (1,0,0) + y \cdot (0,1,0)$
$B_T = \{(1,0,0) , (0,1,0)\}$

To find their intersection, $v \in S∩T ⇒ $

$v \in S ⇒ v = a \cdot (1,0,1) + b \cdot (0,1,0)$

$v \in T ⇒ v = α \cdot (1,0,0) + β \cdot (0,1,0)$

$a \cdot (1,0,1) + b \cdot (0,1,0) = α \cdot (1,0,0) + β \cdot (0,1,0)$
$ b = \alpha = 0, a = \beta$

As $b=0 ⇒ v = a \cdot (0,1,0)$, the span of $v$ is $(0,1,0) \in S∩T ⇒$ the sum is not direct

My classmate's approach (I assume starting here without repeating the conditions of the problem will be fine):

$(a,b,c) = (x,y,x) + (x', y', 0)$

$x + x' = a ⇒ x = a - c$

$y + y' = b ⇒ y = b - y'$

$x = c ⇒ x = c$

$\forall (a,b,c) \in \mathbf R^3$

$(a,b,c) = (c, b-y', c) + (a-c, y', 0)$

$S+T = \mathbf R^3$

He then writes that the term "b-y'" indicates the sum is not direct. I do not have a strong grasp on the differences between our methods, besides the fact that I took the sets down to their basis and worked from there.

Now, I will try to be a bit more agile with my argument and avoid repeating trivial steps,

b) $B_S = \{(1,1,0) , (0,0,1)\}$

$B_T = \{(1,1,1)\}$

$v \in S∩T ⇒ $

$v \in S ⇒ v = a \cdot (1,1,0) + b \cdot (0,0,1)$

$v \in T ⇒ v = \alpha \cdot (1,1,1)$

$a \cdot (1,1,0) + b \cdot (0,0,1) = \alpha \cdot (1,1,1)$

$(a,a,b) = (α,α,α) ⇒ a = b = α$
$S + T = T$

Not quite sure about my conclusion here, but I think it also indicates the sum is not direct.

c) $B_S = \{(0,0,1)\}$

$B_T = \{(1,0,1) , (0,1,0)\}$

$v \in S∩T ⇒$

$v \in S ⇒ v = a \cdot (0,0,1)$

$v \in T ⇒ v = \alpha \cdot (1,0,1) + \beta (0,1,0)$

But I'm a little confused here. What does this last result mean, if it implies that all my variables are $0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reminder: a sum $S+T$ is direct if (by definition) $S\cap T=\{0\}$. Equivalently, $S+T$ is direct if and only if $\dim(S+T)=\dim(S)+\dim(T)$.

For the first case, $ S $ and $ T $ are of dimension $2 $, if they were in direct sum they would span a subspace of dimension $4 $, in $\Bbb R^3 $, that's impossible.

For the second case, $T$ is a line contained in the plane $S$. The sum is never direct in such a case, unless the subspace contained in the other is trivial.

In the last case, you were able to prove that the intersection is $\{0\}$, so $S$ and $T$ are in direct sum (note that since $S$ is a line, it is in direct sum with a subspace $W$ if and only if it is not contained in $W$).

Comment: I see. This is because the $\#B = 2$ in both cases? If so, in my second and third cases they could potentially be a direct sum. However, I see that in my second case, $B_T$ is the sum of the elements of $B_S$, what significance does that have?

Comment: @JakeS It means that $T$ is contained in $S$. Again, in such a case, the sum cannot be direct.

Comment: So in the first case, would you agree that $S + T = R^3$ and that the sum is not direct, and then in the second case $S + T = S$? What is your opinion on the third case, which is the one I did not complete?

Comment: @JakeS For the first and second: absolutely. For the third, I edited.

Comment: Excellent and useful response. Thanks

Comment: @JakeS You're welcome!